# type 'Position' is not a subtype of type 'String' (how to pass object in multipart request?)

Tags: flutter, http, dart, multipart

E/flutter (19556): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Position' is not a subtype of type 'String'
**location is position object.**

````
    var req = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
    req.fields['category'] = _categoryTEC;
    req.fields['title'] = _titleTEC.text;
    req.fields['price'] = _priceTEC.text;
    req.fields['description'] = _descriptionTEC.text;
    req.fields['location'] = location;                   //position(lcation) is an object.
    req.headers.addAll(authHeadToken);
    req.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
        'adphoto', images!.first.path.toString()));
var res = await (req.send());```
````

Comment: ok,i found a hack i am sending location as string **req.fields['location'] = jsonEncode(location);** because dart is converting it as string while using jsonEncode(location) and at backend parsing as **JSON.parse(location);** to make it as json. _it worked for me_ although answer is still needed and will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Which type of field is 'location'? If it takes string or double, then use :

```
req.fields['location'] = location.latitude;
//or
req.fields['location'] = location.longitude;
```

Comment: location is object {
  longitude: -122.084,
  latitude: 37.421998333333335,        
  timestamp: 1641392725077,
  accuracy: 5,
  altitude: 5,
  floor: null,
  heading: 0,
  speed: 0,
  speed_accuracy: 0.5,
  is_mocked: false
}